# how to validate conditional statement written correcly or not?

Tags: compiler-errors, compiler-construction

I have valid structured like this

```
start if 
    start if 
    start end
start else
    start if 
        start if 
        end if
    end if
start end
```

how can i validate for unstructured statement?(syntax error, i.e not ending start if  properly)

Any algorithm or logic would be a help.

Comment: What are you talking about? What is `start end`?

Comment: start end means consider ending brackets for if

Comment: There are a couple of ways: One way is that I look for a non-conditional statement to break the conditional parsing and determine that the conditional wasn't well formed. Assuming you are doing a lexical scan and then a parse prior to a semantic evaluation, it should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use a data structure like a Stack. If you see something start if or start else push to to the stack. If you see end if pop from stack. Then check for conditions which violates the structure. For example trying to pop from an empty stack (meaning that you just saw and end statement without any starts) which should be noted as a violation. Please note that there are more but this should be a good example to allow you to start thinking about them on your own.

The above is valid algorithm which a lot of problems as stated above are solved with adjustments. I would advise reading about Reverse polish notation which is quite similar.